# Can't open Settings URL string from iOS application

Tags: swift, url, settings

I had the following line of code working for a while, but it suddenly stopped working. It should open the Settings to the Keyboard section

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/KE
```

I edited my Info.plist to add the "prefs" URL scheme. [As shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr6fU.png)

Any advice on how to get this to work? I want to open to the Keyboards settings, but if I can only open to the main screen of the settings, that is fine too.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!);
```

I do not want this line of code because it deep links to my Apps settings, I do not want this.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399893/open-phone-settings-programmatically-in-ios9

Answer (score 1):

You can open the main settings by

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!);
```

Comment: This opens to the My Apps settings, I do not want this deep linking.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please check whether your plist right. I use your code can open the Settings to the Keyboard

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard"))
```