# Open phone settings programmatically in iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, settings

I recently have an app summited to the app store and they refused to approve the following code I used open **phone** settings:

```
let url:NSURL! = NSURL(string : "prefs:root=")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

So I got the following code ([How do i open phone settings when a button is clicked ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152526/how-do-i-open-phone-settings-when-a-button-is-clicked-ios)) and got it approved:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

Unfortunately it does not do what I really need as it opens **my** application settings sometimes and other times it opens the **phone** settings.

And I need something to open **just & only** the **phone** settings instead.

Comment: There is no approved way to open the Settings app except for `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`.

Comment: Try with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app
 and
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152526/how-do-i-open-phone-settings-when-a-button-is-clicked-ios

Comment: @maddy, that is ok if 'UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString' is the only way to open settings. But it is weird that it sometimes opens the phone setting app at root and sometimes opens the app settings inside the phone settings. Sounds more like a bug to me as there is no rule for when to open which.

Comment: @karthik, thanks for the tip but does not really solves the question as I am already using what is in there but getting an error that is not covered by the post you refer to.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app/37439140#37439140

Answer (score 1):

This will open the Settings page like shown below.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root=Settings")!)
```

[image: Screenshot]

But unfortunately, use of this code in your application **leads to rejection** on the review process (see the comments).

Comment: 'NSURL(string:"prefs:root=...' made my submission be rejected by Apple. If you are using this code you will probably get yours rejected too.

Comment: @karthik So, what's your result?

Comment: @karthik  I managed to get an app submitted with this code included last month. You can also get a more precise page within the Settings app for better UX http://pastebin.com/SrhqHjth

Comment: @sure Matt. I will try it again.

Comment: @karthik This solution is not working for iOS 10 . I am working on Xcode 8, swift 3. Any alternate solution?

Comment: will check and let you know the solution.

Comment: @LearnSwift From what i researched i concluded that directing user to the Settings app from your app is not allowed in iOS 10. Hence you could show some toast or alert telling the user to go to the settings app manually.. http://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/

Comment: Do you get any way to redirect app to Setting-> Messages-> Unknown & Spam?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 10, "prefs" must be replaced with "App-Prefs".
You can then use this code which tests over all the possible urls.

```
NSArray* urlStrings = @[@"prefs:root=<your_path>", @"App-Prefs:root=<your_path>"];
for(NSString* urlString in urlStrings){
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this legit? Successful app submission doesn't mean that this is legit. It may fail eventually in the future.. can't find proofs :(

Comment: Using 'App-Prefs' is not allowed and using it may result in rejection of the app.