# How to Open Keyboard's settings screen programmatically in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, ios10, custom-keyboard, ios-extensions

How to Open Keyboard's settings screen programmatically in iOS 10?

This code is not working in iOS 10

```
NSURL *keyboardSettingsURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/KEYBOARDS"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:keyboardSettingsURL];
```

and added URL Scheme

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this functionality has been disabled in iOS 10. I believe that https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1924/_index.html is no longer valid. I checked several top keyboard apps and they have either been updated to no longer have a direct link to the preferences, or have a non-working button.

Answer (score 2):

is work in iOS 10+

```
NSURL *keboardURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"App-Prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/KEYBOARDS"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:keyboardURL];
```

key points:

@"App-Prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/KEYBOARDS"

Comment: Is this working for iOS13. I tried but didn't work. Do we have to enable something in the xcodeprojecte.g. URL type?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a URL Scheme to your project if you haven't already. Instructions and more details can be found at this [Apple Q&A Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1924/_index.html). Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you tried using `"prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard"`instead of `"prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/KEYBOARDS"`?

Comment: "prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard" is also not working

Comment: Unfortunately, it's very possible that Apple may have removed this type of URL functionality from iOS 10. According to some of the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399893/open-phone-settings-programmatically-in-ios9), it seems that there has been a history of Apple rejecting apps that use the "prefs:*" URL, so it would make sense if it was removed from iOS 10

Comment: The URL provided clearly mentions that it is only allowed to do so from keyboard extensions. Using this under all other scenarios will cause app rejection.

Comment: I am using this for Keyboard Extension App

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 10, a new url is required. Try using this code which tests both urls :

```
NSArray* urlStrings = @[@"prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/KEYBOARDS", @"App-Prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/KEYBOARDS"];
for(NSString* urlString in urlStrings){
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For IOS-10 or higher,openURL is deprecated. use with completion handler like below.

NSString *settingsUrl= @"App-Prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard";
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 10.0){
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:settingsUrl]]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:settingsUrl] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
     }
 }
```